# Laravel routes returning incorrect model to view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, routes

My 'show' and 'edit' routes in my Laravel application retrieve the correct model via eloquent query but the model returned to the view is always the same. I've cleared my route cache but no luck.

Web Routes:

```
    Route::get('/teams/{id}/edit', function($id) {
        $team = \App\Team::find($id);
        return view('teams.edit', ['team', $team]);
    });
```

No matter which id is passed to the function, the view always shows the team that has an id of 9

The weird thing is if I return the team inside the route closure it displays the correct team.

Result of `dd($team)`

```
Team {#479 ▼
  -name: null
  -company_id: null
  #fillable: array:2 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "company_id"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "teams"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 31
    "company_id" => 14
    "name" => "Initial 3 5.0"
    "current_session_id" => 0
    "created_at" => "2019-12-30 16:17:40"
    "updated_at" => "2019-12-30 16:17:40"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 31
    "company_id" => 14
    "name" => "Initial 3 5.0"
    "current_session_id" => 0
    "created_at" => "2019-12-30 16:17:40"
    "updated_at" => "2019-12-30 16:17:40"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Comment: Your code is apparently right, try with `php artisan optimize`.

Comment: @JesusValera As of Laravel 5.5, php artisan optimize is not longer required.

Comment: The correct syntax to pass data to a view would be `return view('teams.edit', ['team' => $team]);`

Comment: @kerbholz This produces the same result.

Comment: `dd($team)` before you return view to see what it contains. Anything special about team id#9? Are your views cached? Are you on the correct route?

Comment: @kerbholz I cleared the view cache and I am on the correct route. See post update for dd($team)

Comment: Ok then, this seems to be the correct team? From `/teams/31/edit`? Can we see the view then, might be something wrong there. Does `{{ dd($team) }}` in your view return the same team?

Comment: @kerbholz `{{ dd($team) }}` in the view doesn't return the same team. I've found that the following returns the correct team to the view:
`return view('teams.edit')->with('theTeam', $team);` This makes me believe the variable name `$team` is being overwritten somewhere...

Comment: "_{{ dd($team) }} in the view doesn't return the same team_" It should, given your code. You either have a View Composer or something else executing somewhere that tampers with your (view) data. Do you access `{{ $team->company_id}}` or `{{$theTeam->company_id}}` in your view? Good luck

Comment: @kerbholz looks like I have a view composer inside of my AppServiceProvider... Thanks for your help here.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: Great catch. @kerbholz

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was a view composer inside `AppServiceProvider`...

```
        //compose all the views....
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
        {
            if (Auth::check()){

                $team = Team::find(Auth::user()->team_id);
                $view->with('team', $team );    
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

tryout my below example

```
Route::get('/teams/{id}/edit', function($id) {
        $team = \App\Team::find($id);
        return view('teams.edit')->with('team', $team);
    });
```

You've three options, in general, to pass an array to views.

```
return view('teams.edit')->with('team', $team);

return view('teams.edit')->withTeam($team);

return view('teams.edit')->with(compact('team'));
```

in views access it like

```
{{$team->id}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these examples produce the same result.

Comment: Not sure about `return view('teams.edit')->with(compact('team'));`, shouldn't that be `return view('teams.edit', compact('team'));`?

Comment: @kerbholz `return view('teams.edit', compact('team'));` returns the same result.